Jeopardy in Excel Code has the same question come up for every tile on the board
I am trying to make Jeopardy in Excel and the button pressing is already causing trouble. I haven't even gotten to points yet.
If Target.Value = 200 Then
    Set Category = Target.Offset(-4, 0)
    Dim rowIndex As Variant
    rowIndex = Application.Match(Target.Value, Category, 0)
    If Not IsError(rowIndex) Then
        question = QuestionsSheet.Cells(Category.Row + rowIndex - 1, 3).Value
        answer = QuestionsSheet.Cells(Category.Row + rowIndex - 1, 8).Value
        Category.Value = QuestionsSheet.Cells(Category.Row, Category.Column - 1).Value
        MsgBox question, vbQuestion, "Jeopardy"
        If InputBox("Enter your answer:", "Jeopardy") = answer Then
            MsgBox "Correct!", vbInformation, "Jeopardy"
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect. The correct answer is: " & answer, vbExclamation, "Jeopardy"
        End If
    End If
End If


If Target.Value = 300 Then
    Set Category = Target.Offset(-5, 0)
    question = QuestionsSheet.Cells(Category.Row, 3).Value
    answer = QuestionsSheet.Cells(Category.Row, 8).Value
    Category.Value = ""
    MsgBox question, vbQuestion, "Jeopardy"
    If InputBox("Enter your answer:", "Jeopardy") = answer Then
        MsgBox "Correct!", vbInformation, "Jeopardy"
    Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect. The correct answer is: " & answer, vbExclamation, "Jeopardy"
    End If
End If

Here is a part of the code. I go from values of 100 to 400. I am trying to have the user click on a value then the value finds the category and the computer uses that data to find the corresponding data on the Questions page. The buttons work, but every button comes up with the same question which is the 300 point one so I don't know if something is up in the code, but I just can't get this to work.
I have tried manually referencing the cells on the Questions page when the board cell is selected but that led to a loop. I also tried match, index, Application.WorksheetFunction, the different varieties above, etc.
Board:

Questions:


You do realise that Category is just a single cell? I ask because it is highly unusual to use Match with just a single-cell lookup range... (rowIndex will be either 1 or an error with the result that QuestionsSheet.Cells(Category.Row + rowIndex - 1, 3).Value will be the same as QuestionsSheet.Cells(Category.Row, 3).Value)

Ahh ok, I realized I put that in and that caused ChatGPT to go a weird way with the code? Would you be willing to tell me a better way to index the questions?

I'd be willing to, yes, but your question currently lacks the requisite detail, i.e. the layout of your data, so screenshots (including row numbers & column headers) would help, indicating also the location of Target.

I added two photos one for the board and one for the question sheet. Thank you for helping!

I'm not actually familiar with the rules of Jeopardy so you may have to tweak this:-
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C7:F10")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Interior.Color = vbRed Then Exit Sub
        Dim questionRow As Variant
        questionRow = Application.Match(Me.Cells(4, 3).Value, QuestionSheet.Columns(2), 0)
        If Not IsError(questionRow) Then
            Dim x As Long, y As Long
            x = Target.Column - 2
            y = Target.Row - 6
            questionRow = questionRow - 2 + (x - 1) * 4 + y
            Dim question As String
            question = QuestionSheet.Cells(questionRow + 1, 3)
            Dim answer As String
            answer = QuestionSheet.Cells(questionRow + 1, 8)
            MsgBox question, vbQuestion, "Jeopardy"
            If Strings.LCase$(InputBox("Enter your answer:", "Jeopardy")) = answer Then
                MsgBox "Correct!", vbInformation, "Jeopardy"
            Else
                MsgBox "Incorrect. The correct answer is: " & answer, vbExclamation, "Jeopardy"
            End If
            Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End If
End Sub

